# Persisting standalone CollectionType (add/delete)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to manage a list of `Thing`s, any `Thing` have a `name` and an `amount`:

**The entity**

```
class Thing
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $amount;
}
```

**The form**

```
class ThingFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('amount')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => Thing::class,
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

**The form collection**

```
class ThingsFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'entry_type' => ThingFormType::class,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return CollectionType::class;
    }
}
```

**The test**

```
$things = array(
    $this->getReference('thing1'),    // My Fixtures
    $this->getReference('thing2'),    //
);
$form = $this->formFactory->create(ThingsFormType::class, $things);
$serializedForm = FormHelper::serializeForm($form);
unset($serializedForm[0]);            // Removing
$serializedForm[1]['name'] = 'Stuff'; // Updating
$serializedForm[2] = array(           // Adding
    'name' => 'Chouette',
    'amount' => 42,
);
$form->submit($serializedForm);
$this->assertTrue($form->isValid());
$this->em->flush();
```

As you can see, I am deleting the `Thing` `0`, updating the `1` and adding a new `2`.

The form is successfully bound and I can see my new set of objects well formed, however I'm getting only the `UPDATE`d `1` at flush time.

**How can I make Doctrine notice the added and the deleted ones ?**

I'd rather not have to browse the entire collection to make the check myself if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't really need to delete anything after all, here is what I did mainly:

```
function updateThings(array $things) {
    foreach ($things as $thing) {
        $this->em->persist($thing);
    }
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

In another hand, I quickly looked at [`PersistentCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html) which seems to have some embedded synchronization mechanisms ([`getSnapshot()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#_getSnapshot), [`getDeleteDiff()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#_getDeleteDiff), ...) but also seems to depend on a entity relation ([`getOwner()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#_getOwner)) and didn't find any "standalone usage" documentation about it.